# Give a vector function r(t) representing the intersection of the surfaces

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

Give a vector function $r(t)$ representing the intersection of the surfaces:

$x^2 + y^2 = z^2$  and $y = xz$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pluggin in for $y$ we have
$$
x^2+x^2z^2=z^2\implies x^2=\frac{z^2}{1+z^2}\implies |x|=\frac{|z|}{\sqrt{1+z^2}}
$$
so, set $t=z$ and get
$$
r(t)=\bigg (\frac{|t|}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}, \pm\frac{t^2}{\sqrt{1+t^2}},t\bigg)
$$

Comment: @BharatEdupghanti certainly

Answer (score 0):

Given the system

$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 x^2+y^2=z^2 \\
 y=x z \\
\end{array}
\right.$

we get $x^2+x^2z^2=z^2$ and then $z^2=\dfrac{x^2}{1-x^2}$

set $x=\sin t$ we have $z=\sqrt{\dfrac{\sin^2 t}{1-\sin^2 t}}=\tan t$

and then $y=\sin t \tan t$

The intersection is

$(\sin t,\sin t\tan t,\tan t)$

In the picture you can see the two surfaces and in red the curve where they intersect

Hope this helps

[image]

Comment: What happens with your parametrization when $t = \frac{\pi}{2}$?